# What is the significance of this "RED, Digital, and Film Format Size Chart"?

Tags: camera, filming, digital-recording, lenses, 4k

Little context is offered when this chart:

[image]

is linked. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this illustration, you are able to compare the [sensor sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format) of red cameras with film formats like [16mm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16_mm_film), [35mm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/35_mm_film) or [70mm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/70_mm_film) imax and so on.